# Java: OutOfMemoryError when trying to open a 174KB sound file with clip.open()

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm simply trying to play a sound clip using the javax.sound.sampled library, using the most basic example I found in the documentation. I've seen a few dozen examples coded exactly this way and they all seem to work, the file is only 174KB so it's not like I'm trying to play an entire concert:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Clip clip;
    AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"));
    AudioFormat format = sound.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
    clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(sound);
    clip.start();
}
```

...and this yields the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1131)
at test.main(test.java:21)
```

I have literally no clue what is causing this, I've tried increasing the memory limit for the JVM and that didn't help at all. Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the JVM heap size? Might help..http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but have you tested the clip in some other sound player to see it actually plays (ie. it's not corrupted)?

Comment: Also put in a `System.err.println(format);` to see what the format actually is.  If the frame rate is something silly like 22Hz you can assume the file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked into the source from where the exception originated and in this method it is trying to allocate a byte buffer of the size

```
 audioInputStream.getFrameLength() * audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize()
```

if `audioInputStream.getFrameLength()` returns anything else but -1. So maybe your media file returns unusal values for either of these parameters that causes this code to attempt to allocate a extraordinary large block of memory. I'd suggest to check what values you get calculated for your wav file like this:

```
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"));
System.out.println( "frame length: " + sound.getFrameLength() );
System.out.println( "frame size: " + sound.getFormat().getFrameSize() );
```

Comment: I didn't actually check the files source. But using files recorded in a different program seemed to fix it. For anyone wondering I was using the default sound recorder app that comes with Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Java command

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory
```

and upon getting the OOM, the JVM will generate a binary heap dump that you can use a tool like Eclipse MAT or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html) (comes with the JDK).  This will show you what data is being retained in the heap.