# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Very odd behaviour with playing audio

Tags: java, audio, out-of-memory, javasound, audio-player

So i was playing around with playing audio a bit and i found a question on this site which i found some code on which i slightly adapted that answered playing audio but when i tried to use the code i got a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Then i tried starting it with two gigabytes of ram and it still gave me the error,
I honestly have no idea what's going on my code is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;


public class PlaySoundTest {

public static void main(String[] args){
    playSound("audio.wav");
}

public static synchronized void playSound(final String url){
      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(url)));
            AudioInputStream audioSrc = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
            clip.open(audioSrc);
            clip.start(); 
          }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
          }
        }
      }).start();
    }
}
```

And the entire stacktrace is this

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1131)
at PlaySoundTest$1.run(PlaySoundTest.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is really confusing me because to me this code looks fine.
Just to clarify the size of audio.wav is 1.5 MB so with 2 gigabytes allocated this really should not be an issue.

I'm thinking maybe a Memory leak somewhere but i couldn't think why.

I would be happy if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: What happens with a smaller .wav file? I'm guessing your .wav file is currently too big for your program even with the 2 GB.

Comment: Attach a profiler to the program while it runs, so you can see what eats the memory. It could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156848/java-outofmemoryerror-when-trying-to-open-a-174kb-sound-file-with-clip-open

Comment: Even though its 1.5 MB? ok i tried using a BufferedInputStream so i didn't have the entire file loaded 24/7 so ill try with something smaller. Ok tried with a 51 kb file and same thing happens.

Comment: I retract my comment then. I agree with @zyngawow -- profile your program.

Comment: Ok tried with 
System.out.println( "frame length: " + audioSrc.getFrameLength() );
System.out.println( "frame size: " + audioSrc.getFormat().getFrameSize() );
and the result is
frame length: 536854528
frame size: 4

this seems bad right? btw i recorded it with gnome-sound-recorder

Comment: 1) Try it with the *exact* [source in the Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). 2) While some *nix based JREs allow a `Clip` to be of any size up to max memory, note that an Oracle JRE only supports a **CD quality** `Clip` of around 2 seconds length.  What exactly is the format and duration of this clip?

Comment: I am using the oracle JRE i could try with openJDK.


Codec: Uncompressed 32-bit PCM audio


Duration: 17 seconds


Sample rate: 22050 Hz

So i guess i need to play it some other way huh?

Comment: *"So i guess i need to play it some other way"* I guess so.  But I doubt the applet based `AudioClip` would handle it either.  Java Sound with an SPI & streaming of the data should work.

Comment: I don't think Java supports 32-bit encoding. Try 16-bit wavs at 44100 fps, not 22050. If necessary, you can convert wav files with Audacity. I've certainly run longer wav's than 17 seconds, so that isn't the issue afaik.